# How to prevent "IllegalStateException" when using Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, exception

I'm currently programming a game app for the party game "Werewolves of Millers Hollow". When any character in the game should make a decision, a new fragment with all necessary information is created.This all works fine, until I start my game a second time, then, at the first commit, a `IllegalStateException` is thrown.

I already tried to use `commitAllowingStateLoss()`, but this only leads to an invisible UI. Removing all fragments from the fragment manager didn't help either.

My App starts with a main activity as a main 'menu'.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Some Code
    private void startGame(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
        //Some extras
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

This calls the following GameActivity:

```java
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContentView(R.layout.game_layout.xml); //only contains the fragment container

      new GameTast().execute();
    }

    //IOMethod is an interface the game calls when something should be displayed or input is requested
    class GameTask extends Asynctask<Void,Void,Void> implements IOMethod {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids){
    //Starting my game and waiting for finish
      Intent intent = new Intent(GameActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
      finish();
    }
    //Many methods for different views, e.g.
    public List<Character> promptForCharacterSelection(/*Backend params*/){
     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.gameFrame, new IngameCharacterSelectionFragment()).commit();
    //wait for user to finish input
    }

  }

}
```

The Game runs perfectly when executing it the first time, but on the second run, I get the following stacktrace:

```java
2019-07-02 10:17:10.261 4392-4439/com.example.werewolves E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
    Process: com.example.werewolves, PID: 4392
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:2080)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:2106)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:683)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:637)
        at com.example.werewolves.GameActivity$GameTask.promptForPlayerSelection(GameActivity.java:167)
        at com.example.werewolvesgame.ClassicMethod.preStart(ClassicMethod.java:47)
        at com.example.werewolvesgame.PlayingMethod.start(PlayingMethod.java:20)
        at com.example.werewolvesgame.Game.start(Game.java:65)
        at com.example.werewolvesgame.Manager.newGame(Manager.java:42)
        at com.example.werewolves.GameActivity$GameTask.doInBackground(GameActivity.java:105)
        at com.example.werewolves.GameActivity$GameTask.doInBackground(GameActivity.java:97)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Your `GameActivity` code does not make any sense to me .. Is this the all code? This exception usually occurs when you try to make a transaction in a finished Activity ..

Comment: No, this is not the complete code for this activity, but almost. I shortened it a little bit, but this should not be relevant information regarding this problem. I wanted the GameActivity to be a new Activity for styling reasons. I do finish the Game Activity, but commenting out this line doesn't do anything.

Comment: Interacting with the gui is not allowed from a background-thread. I assume (but am not 100% shure) that it is also not allowed to start a new acctivity from background task. You should move the "startActivity" code to the `onPostExecute() method. For details see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Comment: But it says :
"AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows you to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers."